# How to avoid duplicate entries while joining two dataframes in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes wi,

```
Site_ID Town
1235    Fitzroy
2344    Glen Iris
```

another with site_id and business name.

```
Site_ID Business Name
1235    BAC
2344    RFG
```

I would like to have only matched records upon joining two df's like this. After performing below merge function,

```
merge_df_rf1 = pd.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), df2, on='site_id' ,how='inner')
```

I am getting this output.

```
Site_ID Business Name   Town
1235    BAC            Fitzroy
1235    BAC            Fitzroy
2354    RFG            Glen Iris
2354    RFG            Glen Iris
```

Not sure where I am going wrong with my join statement.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour with the provided DataFrames. Your code does not produce duplicates on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Just try specifying `on` only:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='Site_ID').drop_duplicates()
   Site_ID       Town Business Name
0     1235    Fitzroy           BAC
1     2344  Glen Iris           RFG
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry about the late update on this. I did try above. but still I am getting duplicates